# Add CSS (Page Styling) to WiFi file transfer app when open in browser

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-wifi

I am working on an android app to transfer files through WiFi. I have implemented the basic file transfer using FTP commands. When the device is connected to a network then it prompts for a URL to be entered in the browser or FTP client(like Filezilla) and all the contents of the device can be viewed. But when it displays the content in the browser, it does in the default list way of the browser. I want to add some styling to the page like the app Airdroid does. How to do it?

Comment: Did you try creating a server in the android app ?

Comment: @rajatIIT: Could you explain? I did'nt get you.